# where to change the Database connection settings in Orchard MVC CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I set up a site in Orchard CMS. While choosing data storage settings I chose

> Use an existing SQL Server(or SQL Express) database

Instead of

> Use built-in data storage(SQL Server compact)

It has worked fine for me but I am wondering where to change the data source that is the database server name. I didn't find the connection string settings in `web.config` file.

Answer (score 48):

To change the database, you should edit the `DataConnectionString` entry in the `App_Data\Sites\Default\settings.txt` file.

It should look something like this:

```
Name: Default
DataProvider: SqlServer
DataConnectionString: Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=dbname;User Id=username;Password=password;
```

You do need to restart the website after the change is made. If you can't reset the webserver yourself, edit in the `web.config` (add a space) or in the `bin` directory should suffice.
.NET resets the website when something happens in this file or folder.

Comment: Apparently not everything in `settings.txt` is honored:  https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/4224 ("_The connection string is dynamically generated and therefore doesn't use the settings.txt information so the Max Database Size is defaulting to 256 and cannot be increased._")

Answer (score 8):

```
.\App_Data\Sites\Default\settings.txt
```

but you can't just change it to point to a empty database. the database needs to be prepared for orchard cms first.

Comment: Is this un the Orchard.Core appdata, or Orchard.Web?

Comment: Actually, Orchard will create the initial database if one is not present. This is part of the core DataMigration feature.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at .\App_Data\Sites\Default\settings.txt.

Comment: i modified Initial Catalog in dataconnectionstring but didn't work for me.After that i modified DataPrefix but it didn't work either

Answer (score 2):

To change connection string in Orchard you should go to **Orchard.Web**,in that App_Data\Sites\Default\Settings.Txt