# How to update the db connection string with V 1.10?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

Ive downloaded the source for Orchard 1.10 and have already published it to a test server, along with setting up a database.  If I want to run my local instance against that same database, where can I change the db connection being used?
I see a dated post about a settings.txt file here
[where to change the Database connection settings in Orchard MVC CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781063/where-to-change-the-database-connection-settings-in-orchard-mvc-cms)
but I think things have moved since then?

Comment: The post you linked to is correct, nothing has changed since then

Comment: Possible duplicate of [where to change the Database connection settings in Orchard MVC CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781063/where-to-change-the-database-connection-settings-in-orchard-mvc-cms)